# A Python module and package loading confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Let's say I have something like this:

```
.
├── run.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── foo
    │   │   ├── baby.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── user.py
    └── start.py
```

run.py

```
from test import start
```

start.py

```
from .models import user
```

user.py

```
from . import foo

print(foo.baby.Baby)
```

baby.py

```
Baby = "I am a baby"
```

Now, when you run the `run.py` file...

```
>>> python run.py
... traceback ...
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'baby'
```

But, if you change the `start.py` like this:

```
from .models.foo import baby
from .models import user
```

everything works correctly.

When the `baby` module in `start.py` wasn't loaded earlier, the `foo` package object did not have a reference to it (`foo.baby.Baby` threw an `AttributeError`). But when I loaded the `baby` module in `start.py`, the `foo` package object automatically got a reference to `baby`module.

Can someone explain me how this works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submodules are not automatically attributes of a package until imported.

You need to import `test.models.foo.baby` *first* before `foo.baby.Baby` works. You can do this in the `foo/__init__.py` file:

```
from . import baby
```

Comment: After loading that submodule, does the parent module object get modified automatically to have a reference to submodule?

Comment: The fact that many of the stdlib packages and pseudo-packages do this for you automatically (e.g., you can just `import os` and then use `os.path.join`) confuses a lot of people…

Comment: @good_computer: In many cases, yes, the submodule can be found if the submodule was imported. If the `foo` module imported `baby` then *deleted* the `baby` reference again, things get complicated, but in most cases any `import test.modules.foo.baby` makes the `baby` module available by attribute access from parent packages.